# can webpack run without nodejs?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

Some old JavaScript libraries such as jQuery/RequireJS are just a js file, you can use it in HTML easily.

However, now Webpack and other JavaScript frameworks/libraries must install by npm and run in Node.js.

I wonder if Webpack can run without Node.js. I ask this question because I want to do something special, for example using Webpack in the .NET Core or even in just HTML.

Is it possible?

Comment: Webpack requires both node and npm to run. However, there are some frameworks which can run with "just only a JS file" without a complex build setup, like [Vue](https://vuejs.org/)

Comment: @kingdaro I wonder why webpack do not support "just only a JS file" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack is not js framework.

[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) is an open-source JavaScript module bundler. Webpack takes modules with dependencies and generates static assets representing those modules. It takes the dependencies and generates a dependency graph allowing web developers to use a modular approach for their web application development purposes. The bundler can be used from the command line, or can be configured using a config file which is named `webpack.config.js`.

Therefore, it can not be used in html
And run without nodejs

Comment: I think someone whom is using php/.net is so miserable,haha